# "Action Bar" doesn't show up

Tags: android

I am trying to implement action bar(appcompatv_7) on API version 8. Although there is no error in my code but the action bar won't show up, instead it will appear in text format by pressing menu button.
Here is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Code for menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.usingsherlockkk.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Title1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Title2">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Revert">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Title4">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Title5">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usingsherlockkk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.usingsherlockkk.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Guys my problem is that all the menu items are displayed in overflow where only the title appears. I checked it with big/small screen devices but it remains the same.
I hope I have explained my problem well enough. Let me know if something is hazy

Comment: the action bar will show. May be there is not enough space to show all items

Comment: It doesn't man. It is getting so offensive

Comment: post the snap shot pls

Comment: I need at least 10 reputations which I lack

Comment: it should display actionbar. without the snap shot its difficult to say what's happening

Comment: hmm. Well action bar does show at the top but the menu items do not show as a part of it. They come up when the menu button is pressed. I am sorry I can't upload a snap but thanks anyway

Comment: if the items cannot be shown in the action bar ie if there is not enough space and your phone has hardware menu keys it will be shown after you click menu key

Comment: Try getSupportActionBar().show(); in onCreate

Comment: @for3st the action bar is showing but the menu items are not part of it. they are shown in the overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I got the solution to my very own problem.
The problem was in defining the action items in the "menu.xml".
Android documentation says you cannot use "android:showAsAction" on older devices as it does not exist in older versions. You have to use a custom namespace. Instead of saying "android:showAsAction", use "app:showAsAction" and you are good to go. Here is the attachment from official page:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Using XML attributes from the support library:

Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

I hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: Although Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR requires API 11 but I am using API 8. It's a warning by the way, not an error

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is as follows:
There was a line in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

I simply changed it to

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and problem was solved.